# I have 19 redirects but I can't seem to find them-Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have an issue with infinite loop of redirects on my home page. The message appears in all browsers. I tried to delete the cache and cookies, and uploaded a new .htaccess and sitemap.xml, but no change.

Then I used a redirect-checker tool that showed I have 19 redirects, but I don't know where they are set up. I checked redirection in cpanel, but there are none there. There are no issues with the plugin. I have no idea what is happening. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: "There are no issues with the plugin".  What plugin? and how did you confirm this?  Suggestion by Ankit Mehta is good advice for troubleshooting your issue.  We are interested in hearing the results of those tests.  Also, if you don't get your answer here, or for future fyi, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ is the sister site dedicated to WordPress issues, while https://serverfault.com/ is the go-to place for server configuration issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check couple of things

1. Check the wp-config and try setting the site url explicitly

   ```
   define('WP_HOME','http://yourdomain.com');
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://yourdomain.com');
   ```
2. Disable all the plugins and try to access the website if the same issue occurs
3. Check the .htaccess rules if any. Replace the htaccess with the following (Backup the existing one first)

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```